# Prove that there are infinitely positive integer $n$ satisfy $\left(\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor+\lfloor \sqrt{\tfrac{n}{2}}\rfloor\right)\mid n$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Prove that there are infinitely positive integer $n$ satisfy $\left(\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor+\lfloor \sqrt{\tfrac{n}{2}}\rfloor\right)\mid n$, where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Edit: I try to approach the problem by consider Pell Equation $x^2-2y^2=1$, which has proved infinitely solution $(x,y)$. I denote $n=x^2=2y^2+1$, then
$$\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor =x,\text{ and } \lfloor \sqrt{\dfrac{n}{2}}\rfloor=y.$$
I want to find $(x,y)$ satisfy $x+y\mid x$, but we have contradiction since $x+y\mid x\Rightarrow \gcd(x,y)\neq 1$, but $x^2-2y^2=1$ then $(x,y)=1$.

Comment: This is clearly not true. Soon you reach the $n$ such that $\lfloor n\rfloor + \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor > n$, so it can't divide $n$ beause it's greater. Also, if $n$ is integer as you say, the $\lfloor n \rfloor = n$, and your statement keeps being wrong.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso i am so sorry, I wrote wrong (edited in post)

Comment: I try with Pell Equation, by letting $n=x^2=2y^2+1$. Then $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor=x$ and $\lfloor \sqrt{\dfrac{n}{2}}\rfloor=y$. But it's not true since $n=x+y\mid x^2\Rightarrow \gcd(x,y)\neq 1$.

Comment: As it is stated now, the problem is interesting. Is it homework? What tools are you supposed to use to solve it? Please, add your attempts into the body of the question to improve it.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A324175

Comment: @Raffaele can you give me a hint for your statement?

Comment: @Sil Thank you. I had a stroke :/

Comment: Notation/writing: $\lfloor\sqrt{n/2}\rfloor$ looks nicer to me than any of $\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor$, $\lfloor\sqrt{\dfrac{n}{2}}\rfloor$, $\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor$, $\left\lfloor\sqrt{\dfrac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor$.